# What is more apt for posting on user's wall - publish_stream or publish_actions, which permission is required?

Tags: facebook

We are developing an app for a website and would like to take permission from the user to post on their wall, if they approve, we want to post on their wall a small post notifying the connected friends that this person has installed this app. But we are not getting the proper differentiation between `publish_stream` and `publish_actions`.

Also, how to code to post on their wall?

Comment: _“we want to post on their wall a small post notifying the connected friends that this person has installed this app”_ – that would violate Platform Policies – you are not supposed to post _any_ text content that the user did not enter themselves somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`publish_stream` actually includes the `publish_actions` permissions and adds a few more permissions such as

- posting to a friend’s feed,
- posting questions
- creating notes
- posting content to events or groups

If you do not need these 4 extra permissions then you don't need publish_stream. And you must avoid publish_stream , which appears on a second screen where users can also opt out.

> Also, how to code to post on their wall?

Did you searched for this? You'll get n number of the links for the same, I would suggest you to go through the docs once, its not so complicated. 
(Moreover, you have not mentioned which language you are using)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I could get the application working and thank you for your reply.